# How to split multipage Tiff using LibTiff.Net

Tags: c#, libtiff.net

In the LibTiff.Net [documentation](http://bitmiracle.com/libtiff/help/extract-a-page-from-a-multi-page-tiff-image.aspx) I've found that it is possible to get a specific page of the Tiff document.

But, **if it is possible to split multipage Tiff (using LibTiff.Net) without knowing how many pages are there? How?**

Using [this](http://bitmiracle.com/libtiff/help/convert-color-tiff-to-a-32-bit-system.drawing.bitmap.aspx) example it returns only the first page.

Btw, the main problem is that Windows XP can't handle different tiff images, so I want to split it into jpeg ones.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
//open tif file
var tif = Tiff.Open(@"file", "r");

//get number of pages
var num = tif.NumberOfDirectories();

for (short i = 0; i < num; i++)
{
    //set current page
    tif.SetDirectory(i); 

    Bitmap bmp = GetBitmapFormTiff(tif);
    bmp.Save(string.Format(@"newfile{0}.bmp", i));
}
```

The code of GetBitmapFormTiff is from [example](http://bitmiracle.com/libtiff/help/convert-color-tiff-to-a-32-bit-system.drawing.bitmap.aspx):

```
private static Bitmap GetBitmapFormTiff(Tiff tif)
        {
            FieldValue[] value = tif.GetField(TiffTag.IMAGEWIDTH);
            int width = value[0].ToInt();

            value = tif.GetField(TiffTag.IMAGELENGTH);
            int height = value[0].ToInt();

            //Read the image into the memory buffer
            var raster = new int[height * width];
            if (!tif.ReadRGBAImage(width, height, raster))
            {
                return null;
            }

            var bmp = new Bitmap(width, height, PixelFormat.Format32bppRgb);

            var rect = new Rectangle(0, 0, bmp.Width, bmp.Height);

            BitmapData bmpdata = bmp.LockBits(rect, ImageLockMode.ReadWrite, PixelFormat.Format32bppRgb);
            var bits = new byte[bmpdata.Stride * bmpdata.Height];

            for (int y = 0; y < bmp.Height; y++)
            {
                int rasterOffset = y * bmp.Width;
                int bitsOffset = (bmp.Height - y - 1) * bmpdata.Stride;

                for (int x = 0; x < bmp.Width; x++)
                {
                    int rgba = raster[rasterOffset++];
                    bits[bitsOffset++] = (byte)((rgba >> 16) & 0xff);
                    bits[bitsOffset++] = (byte)((rgba >> 8) & 0xff);
                    bits[bitsOffset++] = (byte)(rgba & 0xff);
                    bits[bitsOffset++] = (byte)((rgba >> 24) & 0xff);
                }
            }

            System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.Copy(bits, 0, bmpdata.Scan0, bits.Length);
            bmp.UnlockBits(bmpdata);

            return bmp;
        }
```